# Prevent mouse wheel scrolling, but not scrollbar event. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, scroll

I need to make a webpage scrollable only by scrolling bar. I have tried to find how to catch scroll bar event, but as i see it is impossible. Currently i use this functions:

```
function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
function wheel(e) {
    preventDefault(e);
}
function disable_scroll() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
}
```

But they are not very useful in my situation, because they block all scroll events. Do you have any ideas? I am thinking about it 3 days already and i didn't find any answer (and questions also). Thanks!

Comment: I just put your functions in my console and it seemed to work fine.  I am able to click and drag scrollbar, but the mouse wheel does not work.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 45):

### Prevent the window from scrolling with mouse wheel:

As document level [`wheel` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) listeners are [treated as Passive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721906/104380), we need to mark this [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to be treated as *Active*:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", e => e.preventDefault(), { passive:false })
```

If the ***content*** of a `<div>` (or other element) is scrollable, you can prevent it like this:

```
document.getElementById('{element-id}').onwheel = function(){ return false; }
```

More info about [scrolling intervention](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/scrolling-intervention-2/) and [using passive listeners to improve scrolling performance](https://web.dev/uses-passive-event-listeners/).

---

**Outdated Method:**
<del>`window.onwheel = function(){ return false; }   // Old Method`</del>
[more info](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312) (thanks @MatthewMorrone)

Comment: this doesn't appear to work anymore, getting this in the console: 

[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312

Comment: @MatthewMorrone Thanks for pointing this out. Please check updated answer for the solution.

Comment: @SaurinDashadia, thank you! It seems that if there is a mouse wheel listener on the parent element, you can just return `true` in the `onwheel` function. Then the wheel event will work correctly on the child element, and won't trigger the wheel event on the parent element.
To restore the wheel event for the parent element, you need to set the `onwheel` function to `null`.

Comment: But this approach also block main window scroller from scrolling. It's like I used `stopPropagation()` instead of `preventDefault()` (but I didn't). Does anyone know how to make main window scroll works all the time?

Answer (score 7):

jQuery solution to prevent window scrolling with mouse wheel:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){ return false});
```

If you want to prevent scrolling with mouse wheel in a single DOM element, try this:

```
$('#{element-id}').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) { return false; });
```

The *DOMMouseScroll* event is used in Firefox, so you have to listen on both.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: It actually works fine on Chrome, as of version 78.0.3904.108

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently using this and it works fine. Scrolling using the bar works fine, but mouse wheel won't work.

The reason i'm doing it this way is that I have custom code to scroll the way I want, but if don't add any code it will just don't scroll on wheel.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    // add custom scroll code if you want
}
```