# What are passive event listeners?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener, passive-event-listeners

While working around to boost performance for progressive web apps, I came across a new feature `Passive Event Listeners` and I find it hard to understand the concept.

What are `Passive Event Listeners` and what is the need to have it in our projects?

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md

Answer (score 397, accepted):

> Passive event listeners are an emerging web standard, new feature
> shipped in Chrome 51 that provide a major potential boost to scroll
> performance. [Chrome Release Notes.](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/05/new-apis-to-help-developers-improve.html)

It enables developers to opt-in to better scroll performance by eliminating the need for scrolling to block on touch and wheel event listeners.

**Problem:** All modern browsers have a threaded scrolling feature to permit scrolling to run smoothly even when expensive JavaScript is running, but this optimization is partially defeated by the need to wait for the results of any `touchstart` and `touchmove` handlers, which may prevent the scroll entirely by calling `preventDefault()` on the event.

**Solution: `{passive: true}`**

By marking a touch or wheel listener as passive, the developer is promising the handler won't call `preventDefault` to disable scrolling. This frees the browser up to respond to scrolling immediately without waiting for JavaScript, thus ensuring a reliably smooth scrolling experience for the user.

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    console.log(e.defaultPrevented);  // will be false
    e.preventDefault();   // does nothing since the listener is passive
    console.log(e.defaultPrevented);  // still false
}, Modernizr.passiveeventlisteners ? {passive: true} : false);
```

[DOM Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventlisteneroptions-passive)  ,  [Demo Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPM6172J22g)  , [Explainer Doc](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md)

Comment: so we should always add this lines of code (at least for most cases), right?

Comment: This crashes your js engine in Mozilla. You better detect the browser before attaching this event listener

Comment: @AltianoGerung When the browser recommends it. You will see the message in the Console's Info or Warning tab.

Comment: @yardpenalty.com We can use the following polyfill and avoid the browser checks. For scrolling use cases, using passive event listeners is a big plus.
https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/EventListenerOptions.polyfill.js

Comment: @Vikrant Siwach great advice. Polyfill are quick and somewhat painless when you manage all of them in let's say polyfill.js

Comment: So, in simple words the `passive event listener` is such an event handler that can not call the `preventDefault` function. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Remember that some listeners actually need to block scrolling.