# Handling of 'touchstart' input event was delayed due to main thread being busy?

Tags: ionic-framework, touchstart

I am getting this error when i am trying to start my app

**Handling of 'touchstart' input event was delayed for 2147483647 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.**

**Now I know that this is related to making event handlers passive but what I want to know is how to make event handlers passive in whole project because there are many types of event handlers used**.

I am geting this error in my ionic.bundle.min.js file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152877/consider-marking-event-handler-as-passive-to-make-the-page-more-responive)

Comment: https://github.com/zzarcon/default-passive-events