# Passive event listener on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Passive event listeners are a new feature in the DOM spec that enable developers to improve scroll performance, with a simple javascript piece of code like this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, {passive: true});
```

Is there a way to propagate this feature on jQuery function .on() or the only solution is to migrate all jQuery .on() to addEventListener?

Comment: A little research shows stuff like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152877/consider-marking-event-handler-as-passive-to-make-the-page-more-responive

Comment: I WOULD LOVE THAT!!