# zone.js violation warnings on console in Angular project only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, zonejs, passive-event-listeners

I've an Angular 4 project created using `@angular/cli`, when running the application in development mode, I receive those warnings in the console:

```
zone.js:1489 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 209ms
2[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
2zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
2zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
zone.js:1157 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
```

The weird thing is that warning appear on **Chrome only.** (my chrome build version is: `58.0.3029.110`)

1. What does those (violation) warnings mean?
2. Is this harmful to application performance?
3. How to disable/override or configure zone.js to remove those warnings?

Comment: Face same issue when using material.angularjs. Just added this lib and issue resolved . https://github.com/zzarcon/default-passive-events. Just include in your project and it will resolve this issues.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### What is a passive event?

> Passive event listeners are a new feature in the DOM spec that enable developers to opt-in to better scroll performance by eliminating the need for scrolling to block on touch and wheel event listeners. Developers can annotate touch and wheel listeners with {passive: true} to indicate that they will never invoke preventDefault. This feature shipped in Chrome 51, Firefox 49 and landed in WebKit. [Reference](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md).

Chrome throws the warning ...

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
```

...when you bind to mouse scroll events, to essentially warn that you may have inhibited scroll performance in your event or disabled default events by making a call to `preventDefault()`.

Chrome also throws the error when you try and still call `preventDefault()` in a passive event.

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.
```

Firefox has a similar error for this, however does not seem to throw a warning like Chrome:

```
Ignoring ‘preventDefault()’ call on event of type ‘wheel’ from a listener registered as ‘passive’.
```

---

### Warning showcase

Run the following snippet and view the Chrome console in Verbose mode.

```js
// WILL throw violation
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents default browser functionality
});

// will NOT throw violation
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // does nothing since the listener is passive
}, {
  passive: true
});
```

---

### Resolving the issue

A similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721782/what-are-passive-event-listeners) was made about the implications of this in javascript.

> By marking a touch or wheel listener as passive, the developer is promising the handler won't call `preventDefault()` to disable scrolling. This frees the browser up to respond to scrolling immediately without waiting for JavaScript, thus ensuring a reliably smooth scrolling experience for the user.

Angular has not yet implemented a generic / ease of use solution for this and can be followed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8866).

However due to the fact that typescript is compiled to javascript, **implementing the above snippet in typescript should still negate the violation**.

---

### Performance Impacts

The violation itself is not at all harmful to application performance, however the contents of your event function could be - and thus is why Chrome throws this warning. Note that this warning is only shown in `Verbose console mode` and will not be shown to general users.

As far as I am aware, there is no way to disable such warnings as they are generated by Chrome's interpretation of the code at run time.

Comment: A way to suppress the warning (if using `preventDefault()`) is to declare `{ passive: false }`. The error message seems confusing in this case, since it asks to declare the handler `passive`.