# Passive event listener in Select Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Click on select element shows this warning:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
> 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to
> make the page more responsive.

The problem is that this also expand the height of HTML page in Google Chrome.
Tested in Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)
In firefox this does not occur.

**Simple code**:
https://jsfiddle.net/gurigraphics/2399mnyb

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The same happens with "mouse hover" if you customize the scroll bar.

What is the better solution? I found this theory:
https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself. Also note that the "simple code" demo is nothing but html that does not produce any error as mentioned. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Ok. But, for me this simple code displays the error.

Comment: just from that fiddle demo? and in what browser?

Comment: Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: can't reproduce. Might be due to an extension

Comment: Ok. I've disabled all extensions and it persists.

Comment: No idea why .... unless there is some script missing in your demo link above. It's not like a `<select>` is something new that hasn't been around forever

Comment: Truth. But the fiddle demo delimits the problem to Chrome and simple HTML. What is new in this is these passive events.

Comment: I will report this issue by Chrome Browser Help.

Comment: I am having the same problem. It started recently. In vuejs it kills the reactivity.

Comment: I am facing the same error in my electron app, using React.js. Did you solve this @Gurigraphics ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Just a select element, no styles, no scripts and still this warning.

Comment: @ArchNoob React has an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6436) on this.

Comment: your fiddle is empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152877/consider-marking-event-handler-as-passive-to-make-the-page-more-responsive)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome automatically logs whenever a scroll-blocking event occurs.
Using Chrome's DevTools, I checked that there is no mousewheel listeners on the select box, and it still happens.

I suggest turning off 'Verbose' in the console.