# Can't click on the links of the carousel posts

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel posts in Wordpress. I saw that I can't click on any link of the items on Chrome, but when I use Safari or Firefox it work's good. You can see live [here](http://fundacioncb.es). I think is because the assistive touch of the carousel, in Safari/Firefox can't drag to move between items but the all links works.

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="wpv-grid grid-1-1  first unextended animation-from-bottom animated-active no-extended-padding animation-ended" style="padding-top:0.05px;padding-bottom:0.05px;" id="wpv-column-a24edbc6b7d32aa61617a2493d60fbe5">
    <div class="scrollable-wrapper">
      <div class="loop-wrapper clearfix news scroll-x">
        <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 2598px;">
          <div class="bx-viewport" aria-live="polite" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 493px;">
            <ul class="clearfix" data-columns="4" style="width: 9215%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14175 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-patrimonio" aria-hidden="false" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/09/excursion-a-marvao-castelo-de-vide-y-valencia-de-alcantara/" title="Excursión a Marvao, Castelo de Vide y Valencia de Alcántara">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/conoce-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/conoce-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/conoce-1140x876.jpg 1140w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/conoce-800x615.jpg 800w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/conoce-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/conoce-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            9 abril, 2019 </div>
                          <div class="comment-count">
                            <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/09/excursion-a-marvao-castelo-de-vide-y-valencia-de-alcantara/#respond"><span class="icon"></span>0 <span class="comment-word visuallyhidden">Comentarios</span></a> </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14175&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/09/excursion-a-marvao-castelo-de-vide-y-valencia-de-alcantara/" title="Excursión a Marvao, Castelo de Vide y Valencia de Alcántara" class="entry-title">Excursión a Marvao, Castelo de Vide y Valencia de Alcántara</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>Tras la pasada excursión a la villa de Alcántara, Los Barruecos y el Museo Vostell,…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/patrimonio/" rel="category tag">Patrimonio</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14166 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-exposiciones category-sala-de-prensa" aria-hidden="false" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/vi-semana-de-las-artes-del-reino-aftasi/" title="VI Semana de las Artes del Reino Aftasí">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/reino-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/reino-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/reino-1140x876.jpg 1140w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/reino-800x615.jpg 800w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/reino-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/reino-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            8 abril, 2019 </div>
                          <div class="comment-count">
                            <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/vi-semana-de-las-artes-del-reino-aftasi/#respond"><span class="icon"></span>0 <span class="comment-word visuallyhidden">Comentarios</span></a> </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14166&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/vi-semana-de-las-artes-del-reino-aftasi/" title="VI Semana de las Artes del Reino Aftasí" class="entry-title">VI Semana de las Artes del Reino Aftasí</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>Bajo el lema “El arte te elige” el IES Reino Aftasí ha inaugurado esta mañana…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/exposiciones/" rel="category tag">Exposiciones</a>, <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/sala-de-prensa/" rel="category tag">SALA DE PRENSA</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14163 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-conciertos category-sala-de-prensa" aria-hidden="false" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/concierto-benefico-puerto-dindias/" title="Concierto benéfico Puerto D`Indias">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/puerto-rueda-prensa-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/puerto-rueda-prensa-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/puerto-rueda-prensa-1140x876.jpg 1140w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/puerto-rueda-prensa-800x615.jpg 800w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/puerto-rueda-prensa-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/puerto-rueda-prensa-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            8 abril, 2019 </div>
                          <div class="comment-count">
                            <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/concierto-benefico-puerto-dindias/#respond"><span class="icon"></span>0 <span class="comment-word visuallyhidden">Comentarios</span></a> </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14163&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/concierto-benefico-puerto-dindias/" title="Concierto benéfico Puerto D`Indias" class="entry-title">Concierto benéfico Puerto D`Indias</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>El Teatro López de Ayala de Badajoz será el escenario del concierto benéfico que el…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/conciertos/" rel="category tag">Conciertos</a>, <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/sala-de-prensa/" rel="category tag">SALA DE PRENSA</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14160 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-conferencias" aria-hidden="false" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/conferencia-camina-y-no-revienta-el-lute/" title="Conferencia “Camina y no revienta” El Lute">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/el-lute-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/el-lute-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/el-lute-1140x876.jpg 1140w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/el-lute-800x615.jpg 800w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/el-lute-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/el-lute-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            8 abril, 2019 </div>
                          <div class="comment-count">
                            <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/conferencia-camina-y-no-revienta-el-lute/#respond"><span class="icon"></span>0 <span class="comment-word visuallyhidden">Comentarios</span></a> </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14160&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/04/08/conferencia-camina-y-no-revienta-el-lute/" title="Conferencia “Camina y no revienta” El Lute" class="entry-title">Conferencia “Camina y no revienta” El Lute</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>Eleuterio Sánchez, más conocido como El Lute, ofrecerá una conferencia en la Residencia Universitaria de…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/conferencias/" rel="category tag">Conferencias</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14038 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-literatura" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/27/claudio-portalo-presentara-yilala-en-la-rucab/" title="Claudio Portalo presentará “YILALA” en la RUCAB">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/PORTALO-WEB-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/PORTALO-WEB-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/PORTALO-WEB-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/PORTALO-WEB-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            27 marzo, 2019 </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14038&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/27/claudio-portalo-presentara-yilala-en-la-rucab/" title="Claudio Portalo presentará “YILALA” en la RUCAB" class="entry-title">Claudio Portalo presentará “YILALA” en la RUCAB</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>El actor, poeta y performer extremeño, Claudio Portalo, presentará “YILALA” en la Residencia Universitaria de…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/literatura/" rel="category tag">Literatura</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14035 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-literatura" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/27/indomables-historia-del-general-menacho-y-el-cerco-de-badajoz/" title="Indomables. Historia del General Menacho y el cerco de Badajoz">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/indomables-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/indomables-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/indomables-1140x876.jpg 1140w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/indomables-800x615.jpg 800w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/indomables-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/indomables-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            27 marzo, 2019 </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14035&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/27/indomables-historia-del-general-menacho-y-el-cerco-de-badajoz/" title="Indomables. Historia del General Menacho y el cerco de Badajoz" class="entry-title">Indomables. Historia del General Menacho y el cerco de Badajoz</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>Jacinto J. Marabel, doctor en Derecho y licenciado en Ciencias Políticas y Sociología, presentará el…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/literatura/" rel="category tag">Literatura</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14025 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-exposiciones" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/27/exposicion-igual-arte-todos-los-trazos-tienen-su-color/" title="Exposición “Igual-Arte. Todos los trazos tienen su color”">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/expo-igualarte-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/expo-igualarte-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/expo-igualarte-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/expo-igualarte-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            27 marzo, 2019 </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14025&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/27/exposicion-igual-arte-todos-los-trazos-tienen-su-color/" title="Exposición “Igual-Arte. Todos los trazos tienen su color”" class="entry-title">Exposición “Igual-Arte. Todos los trazos tienen su color”</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>Down Mérida prepara ya las actividades con las que conmemorará el próximo 21 de marzo,…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/exposiciones/" rel="category tag">Exposiciones</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14032 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-literatura" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/19/presentacion-del-libro-disco-rehacer-el-alba-memorias-de-un-naufragio/" title="Presentación del libro-disco “Rehacer el alba. Memorias de un naufragio”">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/faustino-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/faustino-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/faustino-800x615.jpg 800w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/faustino-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/faustino-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            19 marzo, 2019 </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14032&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/19/presentacion-del-libro-disco-rehacer-el-alba-memorias-de-un-naufragio/" title="Presentación del libro-disco “Rehacer el alba. Memorias de un naufragio”" class="entry-title">Presentación del libro-disco “Rehacer el alba. Memorias de un naufragio”</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>El profesor, filósofo y poeta, Faustino Lobato, presentará en la Residencia Universitaria de Fundación CB…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/literatura/" rel="category tag">Literatura</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="page-content post-head list-item post-14029 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-accion-social category-sala-de-prensa" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 262px; margin-right: 30px;">
                <div>
                  <div class="post-article has-image-wrapper ">
                    <div class="standard-post-format clearfix as-image ">
                      <div class="post-media-date">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/18/iberdoex-y-fundacion-cb-firman-un-convenio-de-colaboracion/" title="Iberdoex y Fundación CB firman un convenio de colaboración">
                            <img width="262" height="201" src="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/iberdoex-262x201.jpg" class="attachment-theme-loop-4 size-theme-loop-4 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/iberdoex-262x201.jpg 262w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/iberdoex-1140x876.jpg 1140w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/iberdoex-800x615.jpg 800w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/iberdoex-555x426.jpg 555w, http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/iberdoex-360x276.jpg 360w"
                              sizes="(max-width: 262px) 100vw, 262px"> <span class="icon shortcode theme  use-hover" style=""></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-actions-wrapper clearfix">
                          <div class="post-date">
                            18 marzo, 2019 </div>

                          <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-admin/post.php?post=14029&amp;action=edit"><span class="icon"></span><span class="visuallyhidden">Editar</span></a> </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content-wrapper">
                        <header class="single">
                          <div class="content">
                            <h3>
                              <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/2019/03/18/iberdoex-y-fundacion-cb-firman-un-convenio-de-colaboracion/" title="Iberdoex y Fundación CB firman un convenio de colaboración" class="entry-title">Iberdoex y Fundación CB firman un convenio de colaboración</a>
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="post-content-outer">
                          <p>Esta mañana el director de Fundación CB, Emilio Jiménez Labrador, y el Presidente de Iberdoex,…</p>

                          <div class="cat-cat"> <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/accion-social/" rel="category tag">Acción social</a>, <a href="http://www.fundacioncb.es/category/sala-de-prensa/" rel="category tag">SALA DE PRENSA</a></div>
                        </div>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="bx-controls bx-has-controls-direction">
            <div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev disabled" href="">Prev</a><a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't get the full code because I don't know how these carousel is generated (the website is not mine, was maked by a developer that don't want to talk with us.

Comment: This might be an issue where you need to update the code to NOT require jQuery migrate here.  There are at least 36 JavaScript files on the page - libraries, plugin's etc. that may come into play here.  Did this work previously?

Comment: Yes, it worked previously, I think it's start to failed automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one then https://stackoverflow.com/q/39152877/125981

Comment: First thing I would do is try the latest jQuery migrate plug-in but there is a lot going on on your page here and not easy to see what will be required to remove that plug-in altogether..  This is referenced on the page: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Comment: If a thing of wait, if I wait maybe jQuery add support for chrome like they are on Firefox and Safari? (Where it works).

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga Unlikely jQuery add soon support it. They know about this problem at 26 Jan 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Added non-passive event listener

It is cause:

> Improving Scroll Performance with Passive Event Listeners
>
> New to Chrome 51, passive event listeners are an emerging web standard
>   that provide a major potential boost to scroll performance, especially
>   on mobile. Check out the video below for a side-by-side demo of the
>   improvements in action:
>   https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md

---

Your console log:

> Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove'
>   event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page
>   more responsive. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

---

You need add `passive: true` if you use pure JS:

```
document.addEventListener('event', functionEvent, {passive: true});
```

> Recommendations Add the passive flag to all of the event listeners
>   that Lighthouse has identified. In general, add the passive flag to
>   every wheel, mousewheel, touchstart, and touchmove event listener that
>   does not call preventDefault().
>
> In browsers that support passive event listeners, marking a listener
>   as passive is as easy as setting a flag:
>
> document.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, {passive:
>   true});
>
> However, in browsers that do not support passive event listeners, the
>   third parameter is a boolean to indicate whether the event should
>   bubble or capture. So, using the syntax above may cause unintended
>   consequences.
>
> See the polyfill in Feature Detection to learn how to safely implement
>   passive event listeners.
>   https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners

---

### JQuery does not support passive event listeners

But in this case it is problem with **Jquery**, which have not support **passive event listeners** currently.

Solution options:

1. You need try finding solution on:
   https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871
2. Use pure JavaScript and add `passive: true`
3. Use another algorithm or another lib.

Comment: But I still don't know how I can fix it, what code I need to modify?

Comment: I inserted that in my header file top.php:   function onTouchStart() {
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, {passive: true});} but the console gives the same error. I need to insert it on a concrete script file?

Comment: @Pedro Corchero Murga  Yes is is problem with: `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3`

Comment: I tried the fix that the link gives, included the polyfill but still having the same message, sorry.

Comment: @Pedro Corchero Murga But it does not work with Jquery.