# Should I use touch-action: none instead of preventDefault() to stop scrolling on touch device?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll

I have been trying to stop scrolling in touch devices and I used the `touchmove` event for that as:

```
$('body').on('touchmove.sidebar', function(e){                        
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

In Chrome console I see the warning:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target
>   being treated as passive. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

On [github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2362#issuecomment-262300218) it has been suggested to use `touch-action: none` instead of `preventDefault()`. So my question is:

Should I use both `preventDefault()` and `touch-action: none` or only the later? Would the later work for firefox and other touch browsers?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing the warning in Chrome is because, by default from Chrome Version 54, to enhance scroll performance, it assumes that no `preventDefault()` will be called for document level.

I haven't used jQuery much so, in simple js:

```
body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){}, passive:false);
```

[Check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721782/what-are-passive-event-listeners#37721906)

> Note-1: Make sure that you are providing another way to scroll through
>   your page if it needs scrolling.
>
> Note-2: Try to add the event handler to specific elements in your HTML page
>   rather than the HTML-body if possible.

Now to answer your question:

You do not need both, either one is sufficient. Decide based on your requirement.

1. Check [caniuse](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=touch-action) and if you are happy with the browser support `touch-action` has, go for it.
2. If you are not satisfied with the support it provides, use the `preventDefault()` method.

> Note: `preventDefault()` method will be applied only when the
>   specified event is occurring, and by specifying the style
>   `touch-action:none`, touchEvents for that respective element won't be
>   fired at all, as long as this style is applied.

Do check this link for more understanding:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/

Comment: You have an error there, instead of  `passive:false` you should have `{passive:false}`. This code helped me to prevent default touch events on desktop chrome: `document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){e.preventDefault();},{passive: false});`