# click eventlistner not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, passive-event-listeners

I have some code that when a class is created an eventlistner is created. However it is not working in chrome. It works as it should in other webbrowsers. Every element is and `option` in a `select`.

I do get this warning:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
>   'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to
>   make the page more responsive.

Code:

```
class Form_signal_sender{
    constructor(element){
        console.log("constructor");
        element.addEventListener("click",function(){
            console.log("Clicked");
            var data = element.getAttribute("data-signal");
            var even = new CustomEvent('signal', {'detail': data}, false);
            window.dispatchEvent(even);
        },{passive: true})
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing the error? The message says it's about a "mousewheel" event, but this listener is for a "click" event.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721782/what-are-passive-event-listeners

Comment: @Barmar Yes I am sure, the warning says that on all events not "passive"
I also before found that question and the solution was `{passive: true}` Still not working

Comment: But the code you posted is passive.

Comment: So marking the mousewheel event as passive doesn't fix it?