# Angular 7, why scrolling is blocked on the page when using mat-checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I have not been able to solve this problem for several days, no one could help me. I have a scrolling issue, I am using angular / material in my project and I have a mat-checkbox element. When the mat-checkbox checked element the page scrolling is blocked, I tried everything that could have not effect. No errors at the same time. I tried to monitor the scroll event with the following functions:

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', (evt) => {
      console.log('Scrolling-passive event');
    }, {
      capture: true,
      passive: true
    });

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      console.log('Scrolling');
    }, true);
```

When scrolling works, both functions print in the console, but when scrolling breaks in the console, only the "Scroll-passive event" is printed. In the console, I looked at Event Listeners on this element and did not find any other events, I also looked at css styles and also none effect. And I also have Verbose turned on in the console, and I don’t have messages like this

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive
```

Help please, I don’t know what to do anymore ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 - Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983289/angular-4-added-non-passive-event-listener-to-a-scroll-blocking-mousewheel-e)

Comment: No, I don’t have such a warning

Comment: try creating a demo on stackblitz to reproduce the issue

Comment: I use my Angular 7 project in place with Laravel, and some part of the front is written in AngularJs, and I can’t create this minimum, I will have to transfer the weight of the project to stackblitz, and this will take a very long time