# Getting violation Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event when trying to implement openlayers map and display coordinates

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers map to display a map and coordinates of some ships at sea using Spring-Boot for backend, from where I am fetching ship coordinates and passing them to frontend using a REST API. But getting the following violation which stops rendering of the coordinates

Violation:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Code to fetch data from backend:

```
let geoJson;

fetch('/ships') // replace with the actual API endpoint
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // console.log(data)
        geoJson = {
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
            features: data.map(point => {
            return {
                type: 'Feature',
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [point.longitude, point.latitude]
                },
                properties: {
                    ShipName: point.ShipName,
                    MMSI: point.MMSI
                }
            }
        })
    };
    console.log(geoJson);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Map Code:
window.onload = init;

```
function init(){
const map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    }),
    target: "map"
})

map.on('click', function(e){
    map.getView().setCenter(e.coordinate);
    map.getView().setZoom(6);
})

const openStreetMapStandard = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        attributions: '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">© OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }),
    visible: true,
    title: 'standard'
})

window.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
}, { passive: true });



const baseLayerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
    layers: [
        openStreetMapStandard
    ]
})

const exLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJson)
    }),
    visible: true,
    title: "metadata",
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: "./images/boat-with-containers_75931"
        })
    })
})

map.addLayer(baseLayerGroup);
// map.addLayer(exLayer)
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to implement that passive message handler or any other fix?

Completely clueless with the error.

Comment: Either use a more recent version of OpenLayers which includes a fix (see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.2.0) or use a polyfill script as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55960462/10118270