# Scroll horizontally with mouse wheel using jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use [this jQuery plugin](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-mousewheel) to enable horizontal scrolling using the mouse wheel. I followed [this short CSS-Tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/) exactly. However, I'm getting this error when scrolling on the page:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener
>   due to target being treated as passive.

Here's the exact code used in my main.js:

```
$(function() {    
   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {    
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);        
      event.preventDefault();    
   });    
});
```

I just tested replacing `$("body")` with an exact div `$("#mainContainer")` and it works. I'm just wondering why it won't work with the body as it does in the tutorial?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548261/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener-due-to-target-being-treat might be worth reading

Comment: Can you show us your css and html?

Answer (score -1):

If you get this warning, it means that the browser sets the passive touchmove event for this object by default: true. At this time your preventDefault will not be executed and the page will not crash. So you can remove the preventDefault to eliminate the warning.

```
$(function() {
   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, commenting out the preventDefault got rid of the error but the scrolling doesn't work.