# How to disable scroll function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with "double scrolling"; This is screen from my app:

[image]
As you can see, the space for adding tables is surrounded by a scroll bar. 
**I just need the scroll function to zoom in and out of my diagram**, not to move it up and down. The current situation is that if I run my function that zooms in and out on the diagram, it also scrolls up or down. It makes such a double scroll which makes no sense.

**Is it possible to turn off only the "scroll" function without turning off the scroll bars on the sides?**

This is some code (my event wheel)(i am using library "MindFusion Diagramming"):

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    var zoom = diagram.getZoomFactor();
    zoom -= e.deltaY / 35;
    if(zoom > 70 && zoom < 200 )
    {
        diagram.setZoomFactor(zoom);
    }
    //e.preventDefault();
});
```

And this is an error when I uncomment e.preventDefault ()
[image]

My divs (content is an area with scrollbars):

```
<div id="content" style="position: static; width: 1600px; height: 700px;"  >
        <!-- The Overview component is bound to the canvas element below -->
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 120px; width: 200px;
            height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ffffff; background-color: #c0c0c0;">
            <canvas id="overview" width="200" height="200">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    <!-- The Diagram component is bound to the canvas element below -->
    <div style="position: static; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
        <canvas id="diagram" width="2100" height="2100">
            This page requires a browser that supports HTML 5 Canvas element.
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: uncomment `e.preventDefault()` and put it on the top of function definition.

Comment: nothing has changed, I still have the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var zoom = diagram.getZoomFactor();
    zoom -= e.deltaY / 35;
    if(zoom > 70 && zoom < 200 )
    {
        diagram.setZoomFactor(zoom);
    }
}, { passive : false});
```

reference: [what are passive event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721782/what-are-passive-event-listeners)

Comment: Man thanks!
but I have one more question if you allow.
Is it possible to zoom to where the cursor is? Or will it depend on the possibilities offered by the MindFusion library that I use? My javascript is really bad. // currently, zooming focuses on aiming for the upper left corner of the section.

Comment: Really sorry buddy, I did not about `MindFusion` library :(

Comment: No problem maybe I can handle it. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure ^_^

Comment: I did it so now is the true happy ending. Code for future unfortunates:
    document.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // do not use scrollbars

        PivotPoint.Point.x = diagram.pointerPosition.x;
        PivotPoint.Point.y = diagram.pointerPosition.y;
        var zoom = diagram.getZoomFactor();
        zoom -= e.deltaY / 15;
        if(zoom > 70 && zoom < 200 )
        {
            diagram.setZoomFactorPivot(zoom, PivotPoint.Point)
        }
    }, { passive : false});

Answer (score 1):

I assume you overrode the scroll event to achieve your zoom functionality. You would need to call the preventDefault function on the event object you get in your event listener.

Edit:
Your event listener is passive because scroll event listeners are usually disruptive to user experience. To register it as non-passive:

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    var zoom = diagram.getZoomFactor();
    zoom -= e.deltaY / 35;
    if(zoom > 70 && zoom < 200 )
    {
        diagram.setZoomFactor(zoom);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}, {passive: false});
```

Comment: You should add code example in order for this to be an answer..

Comment: I would've left a comment but I don't currently have the required reputation points. I didn't leave any code because he didn't provide a snippet for me to insert the code into.

Comment: Sorry guys, i just edited post. There is my event's code

Comment: Have you tried with the commented e.preventDefault then?