# preventDefault inside passive event listener ( MapboxGL.js )

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I use MapboxGL.js, when tapping on a polygon I want to call my function (for example, to open a popup).

On mobile devices, there is an error when `touchstart` event (line 103 in jsfiddle script):

> "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation".

Can anyone explain why this error occurs on a mobile phone but not on a desktop computer?

```
  map.on('touchstart', 'places', function(e) {

    const features_in_point = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
      [e.point.x, e.point.y], 
      {
        layers: ['places']
      }
    );
    
    const selected_ids = features_in_point.map(f => f.id);
    const selected_features = PLACES_GEOJSON.features.filter(f => selected_ids.includes(f.id))

    draw.deleteAll(); 
    draw.add({
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': selected_features
    });

  });
```

Here's a JSfiddle with an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/petrovnn/ose40zpL/2/

[image]

Comment: Ok, I removed the third parameter. But the error still occurs.
https://jsfiddle.net/petrovnn/ose40zpL/4/

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721782/what-are-passive-event-listeners

Comment: @James Yes, it does: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#on

Comment: The problem is not with my code, but with mapbox-gl-draw. I study the situation.
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/issues/1019