# Bug involving scrollBy, scroll-snap, and scroll-behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm essentially trying to bind vertical scrolling of the page to scroll horizontally instead. Also using scroll-snapping and smooth scroll behavior to scroll to the next/previous "page".

Please watch the video to see the strange behavior of the script and how it interacts with the stylesheet, you can recreate the bug with the codepen. I'm not sure whats causing the glitch. I added a timeout in the code of 400ms, which was intended to stop users from accidentally triggering the scroll in both directions at once.

The intent is to allow users to scroll to the next element only once the current element is in view.

When scroll-snap is disabled, the scrollBy function does not work, only moving slightly (instead of the full window.innerWidth)

[Video of bug](https://i.gyazo.com/2ec23e2b7c281d26e1e9436d59eec97d.mp4)

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/ubnb324/pen/WNmwOYG)

```js
var waiting

if (waiting == null) {
        waiting = 0      
    }

  document.querySelector(".main-nav").addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();                   
    if (waiting === 0) {
        waiting = 1 
        console.log("started wait");
        if (event.deltaY > 0) {
                scrlFF();
                setTimeout(finishedWaiting, 400);
        } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {                         
                scrlFR();
                setTimeout(finishedWaiting, 400);
        } 
    }
});
    function finishedWaiting() { console.log("finished wait"); waiting = 0 }
    function scrlFF() { document.querySelector(".main-nav").scrollBy({ left: window.innerWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); }
    function scrlFR() { document.querySelector(".main-nav").scrollBy({ left: -window.innerWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); }
```

```css
.a { background: red;
min-width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: flex; scroll-snap-align: center; scroll-snap-stop: always;}
.a ~ .a { background: blue;}
.a ~ .a ~ .a { background: red;}
.a ~ .a ~ .a ~ .a { background: blue;}
* { overflow-y: hidden }
.main-nav {display: flex;flex-direction: row;height: 100%;scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;overflow-x: scroll;scroll-behavior: smooth;scrollbar-width: none;width: inherit;}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav"><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div></div>
```

Comment: It might be better to describe what you are actually TRYING TO DO first here; 
Then describe why it is not working; as it stand it is slightly confusing here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Right, I'm essentially trying to bind vertical scrolling of the page to scroll horizontally instead. Also using scroll-snapping and smooth scroll behavior to scroll to the next/previous "page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse wheel and page scrolling are often a challenge.

This is really just a slight twist on what you have but with some additions to smooth out the scroll.  Not perfect but really only odd on fast up/down wheel scroll.

Things in play/changes:

- Use a cleaner CSS for even/odd color; now you can have any number of elements without altering the CSS.
- Setup a data attribute and target it with CSS for our pointer event; so we just set true/false for that. So setting the attribute value is a smaller DOM hit perhaps and certainly easier to code.
- Small event on the window "wheel" to smooth the scroll a bit. This is part of the "clunky" scroll seen so we just prevent it.
- Some small bit of logic to detect the start/end of the scroll so we can toggle it ON when we are at the start/end.
- Dispense with the `setTimeout` as we can do this with some events - the `scrollend` is the key here where we toggle when it is fired.
- DRY up the code with one function `function scrollContainer(main, plus) {` instead of two; pass a Boolean for the left/right.
- Cleaner with NO globals since we moved the toggle to the data attribute; we can just pass a reference to the "main" to the scroll function.
- Many/most of the `let` can probably be `const` but left that as a separate exercise.

```js
// smooths out the scroll on fast wheel up/down
window.addEventListener("wheel", e => e.preventDefault(), {
  passive: false
});

let main = document.querySelector(".main-nav");

main.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let ct = event.currentTarget;
  let canScroll = !!ct.dataset.canscroll;
  if (!canScroll) {
    return false;
  }
  let w = ct.scrollWidth - ct.clientWidth;
  let sleft = Math.trunc(ct.scrollLeft);
  let wd = event.wheelDelta;
  scrollContainer(ct, wd < 0);
  if (sleft == 0 || sleft == w) {
    ct.dataset.canscroll = "true";
  }
}, {
  passive: true
});

main.addEventListener("scrollend", (event) => {
  let ct = event.currentTarget;
  ct.dataset.canscroll = "true";
});

main.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  // fires a lot as it scrolls.
  let canScroll = !!event.currentTarget.dataset.canscroll;
  if (canScroll) {
    return false;
  }
});

function scrollContainer(main, plus) {
  main.dataset.canscroll = "false";
  let scroll = plus ? main.clientWidth : -main.clientWidth;
  main.scrollBy({
    left: scroll,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* hide the scroll bar w/these two */

.main-nav {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.main-nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  width: inherit;
}

.main-nav[data-canscroll="true"] {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.main-nav[data-canscroll="false"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.a {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.a:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.a:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.a {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.scrollR {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav" data-canscroll="true">
  <div class="a">first ONE</div>
  <div class="a">TWO</div>
  <div class="a">THREE</div>
  <div class="a">FOUR</div>
  <div class="a">five</div>
  <div class="a">six</div>
  <div class="a">last one</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related re: the first function on the document passive we set to false https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721906/125981

Comment: Brilliant response, there's plenty of lessons within it for me to catch up on and further understand css/JavaScript! Always looking to simplify or tidy up code and learn parts of the language i overlooked or didn't learn. If you are able to resolve one more bug with all snippets so far, kindly update your answer. The bug is with scaling and page behavior. When the user resizes the window on any page other than the first page, the left or right side of the page starts to move left or right respectively with the window, leaving you between pages or on an entirely other "page".

Comment: I don't have time to look deeper into this currently but I think it will trigger the scroll/scrollend events as you resize which in combination with the scroll/snap part may be in play here.

Answer (score 0):

While the snippet embedded seems to function smoothly on stackoverflow with adding "html, body" in querySelector for the event listener, the same code does not function properly on codepen or my website?

```
  document.querySelector("html, body, .main-nav").addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
```

```js
var waiting

if (waiting == null) {
        waiting = 0      
    }

  document.querySelector("html, body, .main-nav").addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();                   
    if (waiting === 0) {
        waiting = 1 
        if (event.deltaY > 0) {
                scrlFF();
                setTimeout(finishedWaiting, 400);
        } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {                         
                scrlFR();
                setTimeout(finishedWaiting, 400);
        } 
    }
});
    function finishedWaiting() { waiting = 0 }
    function scrlFF() { document.querySelector(".main-nav").scrollBy({ left: window.innerWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); }
    function scrlFR() { document.querySelector(".main-nav").scrollBy({ left: -window.innerWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); }
```

```css
.a { background: red;
min-width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: flex; scroll-snap-align: center; scroll-snap-stop: always;}
.a ~ .a { background: blue;}
.a ~ .a ~ .a { background: red;}
.a ~ .a ~ .a ~ .a { background: blue;}
* { overflow-y: hidden }
.main-nav {display: flex;flex-direction: row;height: 100%;scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;overflow-x: scroll;scroll-behavior: smooth;scrollbar-width: none;width: inherit;}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav"><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not marking this question resolved yet, because I still don't understand what is causing the issue.
However, I was able to find a working but less than ideal solution for codepen and my website.

CSS:

```
.main-nav { pointer-events:var(--handlePointer) }
```

Javascript:

```
function finishedWaiting() { console.log("finished wait"); document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--handlePointer', "all"); waiting = 0 }
function scrlFF() { document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--handlePointer', "none"); document.querySelector(".main-nav").scrollBy({ left: window.innerWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); }
function scrlFR() { document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--handlePointer', "none"); document.querySelector(".main-nav").scrollBy({ left: -window.innerWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); }
```

For some reason, adding `pointer-events:none;` during the scroll fixed the glitching. I added a css variable to control the property of pointer-events in the function so it reverts back to `pointer-events:all;` when the delay finishes.

When you are hovering over the child element `.a` (or any child) inside `.main-nav`, scrolling does not work properly. It fails to scroll to the next position and produces the glitching shown in the [video](https://i.gyazo.com/2ec23e2b7c281d26e1e9436d59eec97d.mp4) unless pointer-events has property `none`

If anyone has an explanation for what's actually going on, I appreciate any advice?