# Prevent scroll in textbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If my `textbox` happens to be focused and you use the scroll within it, the page scroll gets bugged. In other words, it looks like I am scrolling within my `textbox` rather than the page, which causes me to have to reload the page if I want to remove the bug.

The only work around I have is once the `textbox` is focused and I want to scroll the page I have to click the body of the page to unfocus. Not every user will know this issue and could cause the page scroll to the bug. Is there a way to prevent scroll on the `textbox`? Not sure what this feature is called.

FYI: tried something like this bug scroll still happens

```
textbox {
    position: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nmbga0nu/3/

it does not run the code in this snippet but it shows my CSS. I am using asp.net textbox/label but that shouldn't affect why the scroll happens. has to be something with CSS or bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: hidden;` on the textbox and let me know if it worked.

You could also post your code so we can have a context.

Comment: updated my post. I tried `overflow:hidden` but didn't work.

Comment: try `position: absolute;`

Comment: still bugs with `absolute`. this is a weird bug cuz once you scroll in textbox the page itself seems stuck.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with that exact component and append it to the question

Comment: I loaded my css in the jsfiddle. it won't run but you can see what I use

Answer (score 0):

found an alternative at [Prevent mouse wheel scrolling, but not scrollbar event. JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026502/prevent-mouse-wheel-scrolling-but-not-scrollbar-event-javascript)

I used:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
      window.onwheel = function () { return false; }
</script>
 <script type = "text/jscript">
     $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) { return false });
</script>
```

This just removed scrolling period on the window/text and forces user to drag scroll of page.