# Disable Revslider Mousewheel to scroll as normal inside a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, revolution-slider

I'm using revslider plugin with one page vertical slide and a form in the first slide. I would like to prevent all revslider scroll function when inside the form div.

Can it be possible to prevent revslider scroll function and use the normal scroll inside the form?

Any help would be appreciated !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this, referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026502/prevent-mouse-wheel-scrolling-but-not-scrollbar-event-javascript/23606063)

```
// prevent scroll when inside form div
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){ return false});
$('#YourID').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) { return false; });
```